# apex:tabPanel issue in VF page

Tags: visualforce, ajax, tabpanel

I am using very simple code for tab. It is working in one org but not working in other org. My VF page code is:

```
<apex:page id="thePage">  
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theTabPanel">
        <apex:tab label="One" name="name1" id="tabOne">content for tab one</apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="Two" name="name2" id="tabTwo">content for tab two</apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

I checked console. I am getting this error. See images below

[image: This is console error]

[image: This is console detail js file error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code to your vf page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```